# Permission denied error while installing gem

Tags: ruby, windows, permissions, installation, rubygems

I am trying to install rackamole on Windows XP:

```
S:\development\DevKit>gem install rackamole
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - S:/development/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rackamole-0.4.0/...
```

I have checked permission:

```
S:\development\DevKit>notepad S:\development\Ruby\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\rackamole-0.4.0\some.txt
```

and didn't have any problem.

How can I install gem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing C-extensions on Windows has always been a big and painful problem, as Windows doesn't ship with a compiler. Most gems which are intended to be used on Windows systems publish a specialized gem version with a specific platform field, which then would include pre-compiled binaries. This is not the case for rackamole, otherwise it would be visible [here](http://rubygems.org/gems/rackamole/versions).

Another solution would be to use a version of the gem which uses the newer FFI approach instead of C-extensions to interface with native libraries. I guess this isn't an option here because rackamole, whatever that is, is probably only available with C-extensions.

There once was a Ruby distribution including its own compiler and development headers, but I can't remember the name and I don't know if its still maintained.

Should using Windows not be mandatory, I recommend using a more developer-friendly OS like [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/) or [Debian](http://www.debian.org/) in combination with [rvm](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/).

Answer (score 26):

Running the terminal as `Administrator` user will solve this problem.

Comment: this should be the star :/ Worked for me since installing c extensions was not a problem for me

Comment: AAAK!! How do you do that?

Comment: Been having problems installing any Ruby gem after a clean installation. Tried running things as Administrator, and it is not working for me.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Vlad Lazarenko comment. You don't need to add your account to the local admin group, just right click the terminal or command prompt and choose "run as administrator" and try again installing the rackamole.